# iOS SDK, Text View - make links open in-app browser

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible, using Text View's "Detection" for links, to let the user open the URL in an in-app browser, as opposed to switching to Safari? If there's not a setting for that option, how can I add a handler/event for when they tap a link, to open a WebView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try overriding `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` in your [UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView%3ashouldInteractWithURL%3ainRange%3a), and return NO to avoid forwarding the URL to the OS.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    // Load your webview

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Ok, looks ideal, little confused. The textView in question is located in a custom UITableViewCell I made, where exactly do I put your code?

Comment: When you initialize your textView, you should set it's `delegate` property to some object that implements this method. It could be your view controller, the table view cell, or the textView itself if you make a UITextView subclass